# MySQL syntax error, although syntax is correct

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to simply create a new table in my database. The corresponding SQL query I use is:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), rank VARCHAR(50))`

Entire line of code here:
`connection.createStatement().executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50), rank VARCHAR(50))");`
Yes, `connection` is initialized correctly before.

Stack trace:

```
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND] java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank VARCHAR(50))' at line 1
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1334)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2084)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at de.pc1up.bungeecordsystem.utils.SQLHandler.connect(SQLHandler.java:11)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at de.pc1up.bungeecordsystem.BungeeCordSystem.onEnable(BungeeCordSystem.java:26)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at net.md_5.bungee.api.plugin.PluginManager.enablePlugins(PluginManager.java:266)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCord.start(BungeeCord.java:295)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at net.md_5.bungee.BungeeCordLauncher.main(BungeeCordLauncher.java:67)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at net.md_5.bungee.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at de.dytanic.cloudnet.wrapper.Wrapper.lambda$startApplication$5(Wrapper.java:487)
18:17:43 [SCHWERWIEGEND]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

Don't really know what to try since multiple SQL syntax checking websites told me it's right. Server is running on Ubuntu 22.04 with MySQL 8.0.35

Comment: Rank is a reserved word in Mysql, you should change the name of that column of use quotation marks

Comment: Worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank is reserved and cannot be used. Thanks to *nacho* for answering